# How to automate a calculation in MarkLogic 8 after a document is loaded or updated?

Tags: xml, pipe, marklogic

Is there any way in MarkLogic 8 to create pipe that runs when an XML document is created or updated in order to do some statistical calculation such as count number of nodes in which certain words appear and store results in a file?

Answer (score 3):

You could enable triggers by adding a triggers database to your documents database, and installing triggers. The trigger can respond to create or update in pre-, and post-commit behavior, and run arbitrary code. You could for instance get the document, do the counts you are after, and insert stats inside the document properties. You could then run aggregates to get sums over the total database afterwards..

HTH!

Comment: thank you. but could you give practical example, content processing framework (CPF) give xquery code that i am  not quite familar with. thank you.

Comment: Triggers are explained in detail here, including code samples: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/triggers. To insert properties on a document, you would typically use http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:document-set-property

Comment: Within the trigger you read the file itself with fn:doc($trgr:uri).

Answer (score 2):

You can also look at the [Content Processing Framework (CPF)](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/cpf), which I believe runs on triggers. It's intended to solve exactly this kind of problem.

Comment: Correct, CPF runs on Triggers. It takes more overhead, but is designed to survive restarts, and is very useful for multi-step processing on the background..

Comment: yes it is, but i could not find a way to go through the file and reads the data on it. CPF gives examples to add to the xml file not to read it

Comment: Within a CPF pipeline you read the file itself with fn:doc($cpf:document-uri).